# How to use condition with routerLink?

Tags: angular

I have this method:

```
  validateinformations() {
    this.valid = this.r ? this.r.filter((required: string) => !this[required] || !Object.keys(this[required]).length) : [];
    !this.valid.length || this.message.warning("Evidencija mora da sadrži (" + this.valid.join(", ").toUpperCase() + ") korisnika!");
  }
```

In my html i have this:

```
        <a (click)="validateinformations()" *ngIf="!children?.eligibilityInfo?.disabled" class="choose_offer {{!children.processId || !children.processId[0] ? 'disabled' : ''}}" [routerLink]="valid.length==0 ? ['/evidencija/',type, children.key, query.SPECIFICATION_ID, 0] : []" routerLinkActive="active" [queryParams]="valid?.length==0 ? {processId:children.processId && children.processId[0] ? children.processId[0] : children.processId ? children.processId : null,} : {}" queryParamsHandling="merge" >ODABERI</a>
```

I have problem because for valid i get always length 0 so condition is true and it redirects me to another page. Any suggestion how can i fix that? Because it redirects me before validateinformations execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is redirect on your function:

```
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(_router:Router){}

 validateinformations() {
    this.valid = this.r ? this.r.filter((required: string) => !this[required] || !Object.keys(this[required]).length) : [];
    !this.valid.length || this.message.warning("Evidencija mora da sadrži (" + this.valid.join(", ").toUpperCase() + ") korisnika!");

      if(this.valid.length==0)
           this._router.navigate(['/evidencija/',type, children.key, query.SPECIFICATION_ID, 0]);
  }
```